# Printing value of memory location when data breakpoint hit

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to have VS2008 automatically print out the value of a memory location when that memory location changes. I've successfully set a data breakpoint on this location, however when trying to use the "When Hit..." option on the breakpoint to print out the memory value, I'm not having much luck. This is what I've tried entering as the message to print:

`The value of 0x5844C is now: { *(unsigned int*)0x5844C }`, but that just prints the message:

`The value of 0x5844C is now: <EVALUATION ERROR>`

What is the proper syntax to use in this case? I can't use symbolic variable names.